# Gitignore MongoDB journal?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, github, mongoose, gitignore

I'm new to NodeJS and the MEAN stack and noticed that I can't push my repos to GitHub due to large file size errors.

My guess is these errors have to do with the "journaling" functionality of MongoDB, but as I'm not very familiar with best practices in this regard I'm not 100% sure what the best path forward is.

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: b2920df4c8ef5368c3fa2b92c35c5941
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File data/journal/prealloc.0 is 1024.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file         size limit of 100 MB
remote: error: File data/journal/prealloc.1 is 1024.00 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
```

Should I add the entire data/journal folder to gitignore? Is this common?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend not pushing MongoDB to github personally

Comment: Why do you say that? This is just a repo for sample app that will never be in production.

Comment: MongoDB is like 58MB in binary size so that's a weight to download to begin with and then you are also git-ting your entire database, the journal files will be about 3GB unless you state no journal and pre-alloc of data files will be sizeable too, unlike in SQL where you could save the schema of the database MongoDBs entire schema is done application side as such the only reason you are git-ting it is for the binary really which wold probably be easier to download straight from the MongoDB site when you need to redeploy

Comment: Another consideration is where you might be using this on a OS like Linux/Mac where it is actually easier to use apt-get/homebrew to install MongoDB as a OS service

Comment: I use and prefer https://bitbucket.org/ over GitHub where there is no such restriction even in free tier. However, it still does not make sense to push MongoDB itself for the reasons given above. I have no affiliation with either of the services.